# How to change the direction of the callout line/tail in Visio 2013?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I want a call-out to have the line on the top of the text box, but it always snaps below when attached to a shape.

The callout will be inside the top of the shape in a white space area pointing to a line inside the shape above it.

Comment: Finally found it.  Don't use the ribbon, Insert, Diagram Parts, Callout option.  Instead go to Shapes, More Shapes, Visio Extra, Callouts.

Add a connection point (Home, Tools, "X" Connection Point) to any spot on the page/diagram/shape where you want the tail to attach.

Do a Custom callout 1 and drag the yellow dot to your connection point.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the ribbon option Insert → Diagram Parts → Callout. Instead go to Shapes → More Shapes → Visio Extra → Callouts. Add a connection point Home → Tools → "X" Connection Point to any spot on the page/diagram/shape where you want the tail to attach. Do a Custom callout 1 and drag the yellow dot to your connection point

Answer (score 1):

It appears that for a certain callout shapes, the location of the connector is very limited. For example, this callout type only allows a connector to be located at the bottom:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEYob.jpg)

However, other callout shapes allow the connector to move to any side of the callout box:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sCnG.jpg)

So to solve your problem you need to try a different callout type.